# Pycharm: How to refactor code from inside dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have one dictionary which is in file `dicts.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

errors = {
    'errorMessageNotSent' : 'Your message was not sent',
    'errorConnectionLost' : 'The connection to the server was lost\nTry again later.'
    'errorMessageMalformed' : 'Your message seems to have unwilling characters, Check for them and try again'
}
```

I use it in my code this way in the file `action.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from dicts import errors

def doAction():
    if error_happened_and_message_was_not_sent:
        print(errors['errorMessageNotSent'])
    else:
        print(errors['errorMessageMalformed'])
```

After a while I wanna do refactoring and rename `errorMessageMalformed` to `error_MalformedMessage` both in the `errors` dictionary in `dicts.py` file and in its usage in the `print` statement in the other file (`action.py`).

How can I achieve that using pycharm?

I have tried <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd> but it tells me that `Caret should be positioned at a symbol to be refactored`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dummy variable with the same name.
Now I create `errorMessageMalformed` by adding `errorMessageMalformed=''`.

[image]

Then rename the new variable `errorMessageMalformed` , remember to select `Search in comments and strings`.

A popup will be shown.

[image]

Click `Do Refactor`:

[image]

Comment: This just searchs in one file. What if I had that dictionary in another file? See edit.

Comment: @newpeople It works with multiple files. I just tried.There will be a popup `Find Refactoring Preview` and all occurrences are includes. You can also exclude specific occurrence, of course you can choose all to be renamed.